# Scilab Figure Background Color

Tags: colors, background, figure, subplot, scilab

I have recently started to use Scilab, and in general it works as a good replacement for MATLAB.
One of the things that bothers me though is the figure background color. The first background color of a subplot is always grey, the next ones are white. I can change the white ones with figure options, or with the axle handles, but this does not seem to work for the first subplot of each figure. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

(example code is nothing special:)

```
x=0:10
y=x

figure
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(x,y)
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(x,y)
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(x,y)
```

[Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NC7n.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be an issue with `figure`. You'd better use `scf()`, which is "set current figure":

```
scf();  //always creates new figure
scf(n); //if window 'n' doesn't exist, it creates it
        //if it exists, it selects it
```

I myself always use `scf()` together with `clf()`, which is "clear figure". Try the code below, it should work fine:

```
x=0:10
y=x

scf(0); clf();
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(x,y)
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(x,y)
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: @Luc I'm glad I could help. Could you accept my answer?